# Imprimir secuencia de números

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Cómo puedo lograr esta secuencia, por ejemplo, si le solicitara al usuario el numero `3`:

```
1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 2/1, 2/2, 2/3, 3/1, 3/2, 3/3
```

**Código**:

```
using System;

namespace farey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num1 = 0;
            int num2 = 1;
            
            
            Console.WriteLine("Sucesion de Farey: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Escribe el numero del que desea la sucesion: ");
            num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(num2 + "/" + i);

                if (i==num1 && num2 <= num1 )
                {
                    i = num2;
                    num2++;
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(num2 + "/" +i);
                   
                }

                
            }
            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bienvenidx a SOes. Procura siempre decir algo más que Qué hago o cómo lo hago. Está muy bien compartir el código que llevas, pero también hace falta indicar cuál es el problema con ese código? por qué dices que ese código no hace lo que dices? Así como nadie te va a poner a adivinar en una respuesta, no pongas a otros a adivinar en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo yo lo haría con dos ciclos, de esta manera el primer ciclo itera una vez cada que el otro ciclo itera n veces según el numero dado

```
        Console.WriteLine("Sucesion de Farey: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe el numero del que desea la sucesion: ");
        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= num1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(i + "/" + j + " ");
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```